# XMLWriter for HTML creation - how to add simple non-pair tags?

Tags: c#, browser, xmlwriter

I was advised to use XMLwriter to build HTML documents in order to display them in webbrowser object. Creating doctype and startelements like HTML,BODY is OK..but I am experiencing 2 main problems:

1. I cannot add tags like `<br>`. Using WriteString skips `<` and `>`.
2. The output string is one line - I would need something like writeLine. You know, when I display source its all in the first line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is not a valid XML format, as you are discoving with tags like <img ...>

You could create [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), which is XML compliant (specify this in your [DOCTYPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctype))

In XHTML single tags are writen like this <br /> for example

```
 HTML: <img src="..">
 XHTML: <img src=".." />
```

This link might be helpful [XHTML vs HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/XHTML/xhtml_html.asp)

Whitespace layout is nice for humans to read, but makes no difference to how the browser renders the Xhtml. In fact stripping unnecessary whitespace will produce slightly smaller files.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Indent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent.aspx) property:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream, settings))
{
    writer.WriteDocType("html", "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN", "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd", null);
    writer.WriteStartElement("html");
    writer.WriteStartElement("body");
    writer.WriteStartElement("b");
    writer.WriteValue("Test");

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Comment: This will write <b /> which works for Xhtml but and only "by co-incidence" in html

Comment: Also indent only effects the text output, which has no effect on how the xhtml is rendered.